# How use "package requrie Thread" in TK(wish) file?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, tclsh

I have tried load thread package inside wish(*.tk) file.
Can you please let me, how to use package inside wish(tk) file?

% pkg.tk

```
#!/usr/bin/wish -f
#!/usr/bin/tclsh8.5

package require Thread
```

Error:

```
Error in startup script: can't find package Thread
    while executing
"package require Thread"
    (file "./pkg.tk" line 4)
```

Comment: Do you happen to have some Python apps installed on your system? Do you have Anaconda installed for some of them?

Comment: How python related to TCL/TK?

Comment: Some OSes split up the thread package from the main tcl one. Debian and friends call it `tcl-thread` for example.

Comment: Any suggestion?  how to check thread for tk?

Comment: Anaconda breaks all Tk widgets because Python uses Tkinter and completely change the paths of all Tcl and Tk libraries so that Python can use them. Unfortunately this causes the default Tcl and Tk installation to break. One solution is to install Activetcl instead of the one that comes with Linux. Another solution that I personally use is to disable the Anaconda init script (Anaconda based apps that I use still work without them)

Comment: If you have Anaconda installed I would write disable Anaconda init script or use ActiveTcl as the answer

Comment: Yes, I know. A programming language should never break another unrelated programming language. This is like Java breaking your C++ compiler. I blame the Anaconda developers for this. Fun fact: the same company/organisation maintaining Anaconda is also the one maintaining ActiveTcl

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Thread package is not on the path of locations that Tcl searches when looking for packages.

***The standard way of fixing this is via the `TCLLIBPATH` environment variable.***

You need to find the directory containing the implementation and put the *parent directory* of that directory in the environment variable before starting the Tcl interpreter. On my system, where the actual implementation is in `/opt/local/lib/thread2.8.5/libthread2.8.5.dylib`, that would be done via:

```sh
export TCLLIBPATH=/opt/local/lib
```

but the locations and filenames most certainly can vary between systems! (The correct location ought to be there by default, but there are ways for other software to cause problems with this. It's really irritating!) Note that you should use `/` instead of `\` as the latter is a Tcl metacharacter. If there are multiple locations, the `TCLLIBPATH` actually contains a space-separated list.

---

Note that this is different to handling your own application-specific packages. In that case, you should `lappend auto_path $location` the place (or places) to get them from at the start of your main script.